# How to set field, specific for enum value?

Tags: java, enums

This code is working

```
public enum MyEnum{
    ONE("str"),
    TWO("smth");

    MyEnum(String str){this.foo=str;}
    String foo;

}
```

But I want to add some specific fields for each enum value:

```
enum MyEnum{
        ONE("str"){
            int bar1;
        },
        TWO("smth"){
            Date bar2;
        };

        MyEnum(String str){this.foo=str;}
        String foo;
    }
```

I understand that I can write:

```
int bar1=12;
```

But can I set this value in constructor?

Comment: this looks *wild*, why do you need that?

Comment: Just out of interest: How do you plan to use those fields?

Comment: Since your enum values are _instances_ of the enum (class) how should a shared constructor support different fields? You could either directly set them in the "subclass" initializer, i.e. `int bar1=12;` or otherwise just provide the fields for _all_ enums and just set those you need and leave the others `null` or `0` (or whatever you want as a special "not set" value for ints and other primitives).

Comment: you can't - thats the point in using `enum`s in the first place

Comment: but you know that enums are just classes treated a bit different right? you can create immutable `final class`es for example that would mimic this probably

Comment: Obviously it is not duplicate